# Nested class initialize not being called

Tags: ruby

I am creating a custom Trie as follows:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

    class CustomTrie
      attr_accessor :trie

      def initialize(items)

      end

      def self.parse_to_trie(items)

      end

      def get(path)

      end

      class Node
        attr_accessor :key, :parent, :children,

        def initialize(key: '', parent: nil, children: [])
          # This isn't being called, why?
          @key = key
          @parent = parent
          @children = children
        end

        def is_parent?

        end

        def is_leaf?

        end

        def inspect
          {key: @key, parent: @parent, children: @children}
        end
      end

      class Trie
        attr_accessor :root

        def initialize(root = Node.new)
          @root = root
        end

        def add(path)

        end

        def get(path)

        end
      end
    end
```

However when I try calling `CustomTrie::Node.new` everything is initialized to nil instead of the default values, and when I try calling the constructor with values I get the error: "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given x, expected 0))"

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to identify what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:facepalm:

It turns out it was because I had a comma after `:children` in my `attr_accessor` call.

Comment: Trailing commas are allowed, but then the method call should be called with parentheses to signal where to stop the parameter list. `attr_accessor(:key, :parent, :children,)`  should work for example. Without the parentheses it defines the `initialize` method, this returns the symbol `:initialize` which is then used in as next parameter for `attr_accessor`. The behaviour would be the same as `def initialize; ...; end; attr_accessor :initialize` redefining the initializer with the getter generated from `attr_accessor`.